# Returning results form a database query without using Scan - Golang

Tags: go

From what I can gather, in Go the way to fetch data from a database is generally something like described here: http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html

Doing something along the lines of :

```
rows, err := db.Query("select id, name from users where id = ?", 1)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    err := rows.Scan(&id, &name)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(id, name)
}
```

If i wanted to create a wrapper for database access though I wouldnt be able to do the Scan in there and i would rather not return the rows to do that with. Is there any way to get the objects returned from the rows other than Scan? They would all be interface{}'s probably but thats totally fine. Failing that, if I iterate through the rows is there a way to get access ot the object so I could cast to a given struct or anything?

Comment: I believe there isn't a way to avoid `Scan`. You can probably scan into `[]*interface{}`, where its length is determined with [`rows.Columns`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Columns). Not sure what the gain is, though

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get the objects returned from the rows other than Scan?

No.

> if I iterate through the rows is there a way to get access ot the object so I could cast to a given struct or anything?

No, not in they way you imagine (e.g. there are no casts in Go).

Scan them into whatever fits your needs, from `interface{}` to `sql.RawBytes` or smth implementing Scanner. Please consult the documentation of package database/sql, especially database/sql.Rows.Scan (https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Rows.Scan) . Most of the time it's quicker to look at the documentation.

Comment: Not sure on the terminology in Go but you can do something like obj.(MyStruct). thats what i was referring to as casting. If I was to Scan to  an interface, I would still need to know what fields I want at that point. Thats the part I would like to genericize

Comment: @discodowney obj.(MyStruct) is called a type assertion and has nothing to do with "casting". Please take the Tour of Go for fundamentals and terminology. From what I understand of your undertaking: You will fail.